# Program / browser extension that sends me an email or save somewhere my weekly Facebook activity

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a browser extension (ideally Chrome) or program (ideally supporting Windows 7) to send me an email or save somewhere my Facebook activity log every week (since the Facebook activity log is only 7-day long).